# Calling method on an object, and using same object as parameter for method

Tags: java, methods

I am working on a java program for creating a slot machine. The program works how I want it to but I am not sure if one of my method calls is proper java etiquette. In my main method below, inside my for loop, I call the method rollAndCompare() on the FourTumblers object, machine. This method returns an integer, coin, which represents how much the user won based on the number of tumblers matched. This if-else statement is written in the FourTumblers class. However, I also pass the same machine object as a parameter so that the method can access the tumbler values of the object. Is there a better way to do this? Is this correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int coins;
    int addtLives;
    int bank = 0;
    int lives = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter how many games you want to play:");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have decided to play " + num + " games.\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        FourTumblers machine = new FourTumblers();
        coins = machine.rollAndCompare(machine);
        bank += coins;
        addtLives = coins/100;
        lives += addtLives;
        System.out.println("You won " + coins + " coins. That's " + addtLives + " lives.");
        System.out.println("You now have a total of " + bank + " coins and " + lives + " lives.\n");
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Here is my rollAndCompare method...

```
public int rollAndCompare(FourTumblers machine) {
    value1 = machine.getValue1();
    value2 = machine.getValue2();
    value3 = machine.getValue3();
    value4 = machine.getValue4();

    if ((value1 == value2)&&(value2 == value3)&&(value3 == value4)){
        System.out.println(value1 + " | " + value2 + " | " + value3 + " | " + value4);
        System.out.println("Jackpot!");
        coins = 600;
        return coins;
    }
    else if (((value1 == value2)&&(value2 == value3))||((value1 == value3)&&(value3 == value4))||((value1 == value2)&&(value2 == value4))||((value2 == value3)&&(value3 == value4))){
        System.out.println(value1 + " | " + value2 + " | " + value3 + " | " + value4);
        coins = 300;
        return coins;
    }
    else if ((value1 == value4)||(value1 == value2)||(value1 == value3)||(value2 == value3)||(value2 == value4)||(value3 == value4)){
        System.out.println(value1 + " | " + value2 + " | " + value3 + " | " + value4);
        coins = 100;
        return coins;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(value1 + " | " + value2 + " | " + value3 + " | " + value4);
        coins = 0;
        return coins;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `machine.rollAndCompare()` it should still be able to access the values of machine. Try it by removing the `FourTumblers machine` from the method `public int machine.rollAndCompare(FourTumblers machine)` and it should still work.

Comment: Just make the `tumbler` a class variable, then any member of the class will be able to access it without you need to pass it as argument. Cos your current design is a bit.... (confusing?)

Comment: inside the rollAndCompare() method I call a getValue() method for each of the four tumbler objects that make up the FourTumblers object. I need to pass machine as a parameter so that the getValue methods can access the four tumblers of the machine

Comment: You can call that using `this.getValue()`, you don't need to pass `machine`.

Answer (score 0):

The times you would want to add an object onto itself in a class is if you are going to compare it with other objects from the same class.

Ex:

```
public class Sample
{
private String name = "Sample Chocolate";
private int cost = 1;

public boolean compareSample(Sample sample) 
{
    if (sample.name.equals(name) && cost == sample.cost)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then from another class:

```
public class SampleTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Sample sample1 = new Sample();
        Sample sample2 = new Sample();
        System.out.println("Are sample one and sample two the same?: " + sample1.compareSample(sample2));
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can simply put nothing inside the parenthesis:

```
public boolean compareSample() 
{
    if (name.equals("Sample Chocolate") && cost == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

As Ashiquzzman eloquently said: **You can call that using this.getValue(), you don't need to pass machine** (to be used as `machine.getValue()`).